# Why am I getting extra padding below my dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css

Trying to make a drop down menu with css but it has some weird bugs in it. Here is the link for the site I'm working on.

http://shekinahgloryfire.com/?page=about

My CSS is like this:

```
#nav ul{float:left;margin-top:95px;list-style:none;padding-left:140px;}
#nav .first{border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;-webkit-border-radius:10px 0 0 10px; -moz-border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;}
#nav .last{border-radius:0px 10px 10px 0;-webkit-border-radius:0px 10px 10px 0; -moz-border-radius:0px 10px 10px 0;}
#nav ul li{float:left;border:solid #000;border-width:1px 0 1px 1px;background:black url('../images/navbg.gif');overflow:hidden}
#nav ul li:hover{background:#f68f1e url('../images/activebg.gif')}
#nav ul li a:link{text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:none; font-family:serif; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold; color:#fff; width:100px; height:40px; display:block; text-align:center; padding-top:10px}
#nav ul li a:hover{color:#000;text-decoration:underline;}
#nav ul ul{ position:absolute; }
```

And my mark up is like this:

```
<div id="nav">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="first"><a class="first" style="<?php if($page == "home") print "background:#f68f1e url('images/activebg.gif');color:#000";?>" href="?page=home">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="?page=about" style="<?php if($page == "about") print "background:#f68f1e url('images/activebg.gif');color:#000;";?>">About</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="?page=about">Testimonies</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="?page=resources" style="<?php if($page == "resources") print "background:#f68f1e url('images/activebg.gif');color:#000;";?>">Resources</a></li>
                                <li><a href="?page=videos" style="<?php if($page == "videos") print "background:#f68f1e url('images/activebg.gif');color:#000;";?>">Videos</a></li>
                                <li class="last"><a href="?page=contact" class="last" style="<?php if($page == "contact") print "background:#f68f1e url('images/activebg.gif');color:#000";?>">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Comment: I'm not even seeing a drop down menu on Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saying about spacing between the logo+nav and the actual content, then you need to decrease the height value in .header class of your stylesheet.

Comment: I fixed the spacing but I can't get the drop down to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just rewrote the whole navigation from scratch. Then I decided to do away with the dropdown and just put it on the side navigation.